# public Sheet - GET access with api key works for days then permission denied

Tags: google-sheets-api

This has happened on 3 separate Google Sheets now. I have a Sheet set up with "anyone with link can view". I also have the Sheet set up for editing by a few specific individuals. I access the Sheet from an XSLT transform using a url like this:
`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<sheet_id>?key=<my_key>`

Everything works swimmingly. Then some hours later the same request results in this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I then double-check the permissions on the Sheet and everything is as it was: anyone can view & a few editors. Changing permissions to not public and then public again does not work.

Oauth access works, but I need to access with a GET request from XSLT and I can't use an Oauth api.

My only fix so far is to create a new blank Sheet and then copy in the tabs from the old sheet to the new one. Then I simply change the Sheet id in my GET request and all works fine.

This really seems like a bug to me (permissions somehow get corrupted and can't be restored), but I'm not sure how to confirm that.

There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to when it stops working. Can anyone help me debug or figure out a workaround? Creating new Sheets and copying in the data every time it breaks isn't feasible.

Thanks!

Comment: Has your api key expired.

Comment: No, because I use the same key with a different Sheet id and it works fine. Also I currently have about 8 Sheets I'm fetching with the same key, and only one or two give the "Permission Denied" response.

Comment: Are they hosted on Google Drive or Google Team Drive?

Comment: Plain 'ol Drive

Comment: Turns out the permission issue is transitory. If I wait a few hours it often works again. But then it starts failing again later.

Comment: Looks like it's a Sheets API bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111262653

Comment: Having this same problem. Very frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Google Sheets bug:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111262653

It has been resolved.